# Heroku deploy with ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, node.js, heroku

I'm tring to send an email to activate the account and search the internet. I've found Heroku service.

Now, after reading some guides, including the official one, I've tried to deploy my app using ruby and and nodejs buildpacks and still got this error:

```
   ----> Failed to detect app matching no buildpack
   More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
   !     Push failed
```

Now I've tried adding ruby version in my gem files and still don't work.

This is [my repo](https://github.com/Klunkh/CarAdvisor).

Comment: Your app is supposed to be in the root

Answer (score 0):

Heroku can't detect the type of application that you're deploying if your application files aren't in the root folder.

The best thing to do would be to move all the files from `/CarAdvisor` into the root folder, and then commit and redeploy.

The other thing you could try is to provide a `Procfile` in the root folder, so that Heroku knows how to start up your app:

```
# Procfile
web: bundle exec CarAdvisor/puma -C CarAdvisor/config/puma.rb
```